# Bash shell script for time search

Tags: bash, shell

I have files which contain lines starting with date-time format as below:

```
Tue Nov 21 07:56:31 IST 2017----line continued.
Tue Nov 21 08:28:21 IST 2017----line continued.
```

Now I want to write a script to search lines in which the `08:24:20` time is included.

More in detail: the time 08:24:20 is not present in the file. the file contain the bounds of a range in time: e.g from Tue Nov 21 07:56:31 to Tue Nov 21 08:28:21

It updates every minutes.

It means I just grep "Tue Nov 21" and i have to guess that time 08:24:20 is present in the range (i.e from Tue Nov 21 07:56:31 to Tue Nov 21 08:28:21).

thanks

Can anybody help me?

Comment: have you tried `grep`? For help, type in your command line `man grep` (unix like systems, linux, mac)

Comment: Does each range fit into a single day - aren't there ranges from 23:20 to 01:07 for example? Is the start of range always in an even row (counting from zero)? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy you just need to use `grep` command like below:-

```
 grep "08:24:20" file.txt > output.txt
```